# Using KDE in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, kde

I just installed Debian Squeeze and it defaulted to the gnome desktop environment. I have installed KDE via the package manager but do not know how to set it as the default environment. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose what Desktop you want during log-in. That is, instead of just entering your username and password, go to something named along the lines of *Choose desktop session* and select KDE. From there, proceed to entering your username and password, and you should find yourself inside of a KDE desktop.